# selecting a column name "delete" in the dbt query to create a VIEW

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am trying to create a VIEW in dbt. The source table has a column named `delete`. How do I select this column in the select query in DBT?

I tried :

```
select id, delete from src_table;
select id, "delete" from src_table;
select id, "DELETE" from src_table;
select id, DELETE from src_table;
```

but neither of them worked. Please advise.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to answer this question with only this information. What warehouse are you using?  What error are you getting?  For instance if you're using snowflake you probably want to capitalize delete in quotes, a modification of the second thing you tried.

Comment: We are on Snowflake. I have tried "DELETE", "delete", DELETE, and delete. But no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague helped figure this out. In addition to having the delete in double quotes, need to have a model YAML as following:

```
version: 2

models:
  - name: model_name
    columns:
      - name: delete
        quote: true
```

once this yaml definition is created, `select id, "delete" from src_table` should work.

Comment: Sounds like you might have been persisting docs?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your column is not actually named exactly `DELETE`. If it were, then you would select it with `select "DELETE"`.

To prove that point, I just tried to reproduce your issue, but couldn't with this query:

```sql
create table if not exists delete_test as (
    select 1 as id, FALSE as "DELETE"
    union all
    select 2 as id, TRUE as "DELETE" 
)
;
-- this works
select id, "DELETE" from delete_test;
```

To find out exactly the name of the column you're trying to select, you could use `show columns`:

```sql
show columns in table delete_test;
```

You can then select the value that looks like `DELETE` and copy it to your clipboard (this is showing the snowsight UI):

[image]

I suspect you'll find some whitespace when you paste that value into a text editor.

Comment: what version of the dbt are you using?

Comment: I don't think dbt has anything to do with this. There are [quoting configs](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-properties/quoting) and the defaults are different for snowflake, but those only apply to database/schema/table names, not field names. What does your compiled query (in your target directory) look like? Is this in a custom generic test? Are you using a macro like dbt_utils.pivot?